# MS Teams Bot to manipulate audio stream from user

Tags: microsoft-teams, audio-processing

I wanted to build a small Bot for MS Teams who can remove noise from incoming users audio Stream. The edited audio stream should then be passed on to the call participants.

I already searched the Bot documentation on Microsoft but didn't find a definite yes or no.

Can someone please elaborate?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: good luck ... microsoft spent billions to purchase skype which I will speculate was the nugget it used to create Teams so I'd be surprised if they expose a hook where you could insert such a proposed callback ... hey but anything's possible

Comment: You can get the call information using calling bot. Calling bot is used to call and join the meetings, You will receive an event when bot joins the call there you can perform the required actions. Here is the document for [calling Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) and [Example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/RemoteMediaSamples/IncidentBot).

Comment: Yes, so a bot is not capable to manipulate an audio stream and pass it on to other callers. I think @ScottStensland is right with Microsoft not giving access to the audio data stream... Which is quite unfortunate.

Comment: Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=desktop)? try if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can get the call information using calling bot. Calling bot is used to call and join the meetings, You will receive an event when bot joins the call there you can perform the required actions. Here is the document for [calling Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) and [Example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/RemoteMediaSamples/IncidentBot)